# What editor to use with Agile Toolkit?

Tags: php, frameworks, editor, atk4

im totaly new to Agile Toolkit, just put it on my server :)

im looking around, writing some stuff etc, but for begining its really a lot of objects, funcions etc, so it would be nice to load all the stuff in some editor (ultraedit ..) to know what is available in object

Wich tools you use when developing with AT?

Thanks, Peter

Comment: maybe a little akward questions, for autocmplete (ctrl+space) i would like to see all the functions of some object, lets say: $this->api->auth->check();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried Zend Studio and is just the thing i was looking for.
Just look at this image:

[image]

Comment: OK so far so good (for $this), but what Zend framework will offer you in the next line when you write `$m->`? I guess nothing or only methods from AbstractObject not methods of Model_Scheduler_Job. Can you please try that?

Comment: By the way, thanks for trying out my add-on from ds-addons pack :) Just be sure to download latest version from git: https://github.com/DarkSide666/ds-addons

Comment: Hi, i tried, and afcourse only methods fom abstract object.. I little better that plain text editor, but still not the right thing.. I checked the github, but the last version is from 4 months, so i guess im using it already :) btw, i added class properties to addon ;) thnx to you, very cool add-on!

Comment: If you have any upgrade to that add-on ready which you would like to share, then please feel free to make a pull request in github :)

Answer (score 1):

No editor will help you with this because IDEs actually work only for strong-typed languages. PHP is not such language and dynamic object creating with ATK is even more "dynamic" and unpredictable by IDE.

For example, no editor will "understand" this:

```
$obj = $this->add('MyCoolObjectClass');
$obj->doSomething();
```

There is no way editor will understand class of $obj, so it simply can't offer you available attributes and methods of this object.

Answer (score -1):

Try for example "ELRTE". But any Jquery based editor should be okay.

Comment: Peter is not asking for HTML editors. What he's asking about is about "IDE"s - editor for development.